# Show only first match from *ngIf expression

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

How can I show only one (first) match from the *ngIf.

I have an object loop with *ngFor following with *ngIf expression containing items with same Id's and different dates. 
I want to filter and show only the one with most recent date, not duplicating them, since I filter by objectId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html file:

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
  <div *ngIf="item.id == matchWithCondion ?func():false">
    Add your code here
  </div>
</div>
```

In typescript file initialize a variable as:

```js
let isFirstMatch = false;
 constructor(){}

 func() {
   if (!isFirstMatch) {
     this.isFirstMatch = true;
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

In html file:

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
  <div *ngIf="item.id == matchWithCondion ? func() : false">
Add your code here
  </div>
</div>
```

In typescript file initialize a variable as:

```
let isFirstMatch = false;
```