# Only first match from *ngIf directive returns ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a nested ngif inside ngfor:

```
<ion-content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of (results | async)">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let elements of item.bc; first as isFirst; index as i">
        <ng-container *ngIf="elements.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00' ?func():false">
          <ion-item>{{elements.Event.StartTime | date:'shortTime'}}</ion-item>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

I saw the resolution with a function from here: [Show only first match from *ngIf expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572202/show-only-first-match-from-ngif-expression)

```
export class Tab4Page implements OnInit {

  results: Observable<any>;
  isFirstMatch = false;

  constructor(private channel: Service) {
  }

func() {
    if (this.isFirstMatch === false) {
      this.isFirstMatch = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.results = this.channel.searchData();
  }

}
```

But it did not work for me. I get this error:

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.

Is there a better way to output only the first match? Or if not, can you please tell me how should I fix the ExpressionChanged error.

Comment: Why not structuring the data as you wish before you use it in the Template and get rid of unnecessary hacks? in this case you can subscribe to the observable/using map operator make the filtering there instead of trying to ```break``` inside the html.

Comment: Thanks, Yochai! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the first occurence inside your ts :

html

```
<ion-content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of (results | async)">
      <ng-container *ngIf="findFirstElement(item.bc) as element">
          <ion-item>{{element.Event.StartTime | date:'shortTime'}}</ion-item>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

ts

```
  findFirstElement(item : any[]){
    if (!this.isFirstMatch && item.some(el => el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00')){
      this.isFirstMatch = true ;
      return item.find(el => el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00') ;
    }

    return null ;
  }
```

**update**

I think that isFirstMatch flag is no more needed because you want to render the first occurencce for each iteration (item) :

```
  findFirstElement(item : any[]){
      return item.find(el => el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00') ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it in code:

```
this.firstMatches$ = this.results.pipe(
  map(results => // rx map operator
    results.map(item => // array map operator to transform
      item.bc.find(el => // into first found match
        el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00')))
);


<ion-content>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of (firstMatches$ | async)">
    <ion-item>{{item.Event.StartTime | date:'shortTime'}}</ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

OR:

```
this.firstMatch$ = this.results.pipe(
  map(results => // rx map operator
    results.find(item => // find first item
      !!item.bc.find(el => // that contains a match
        el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00'))),
  map(item => item.bc.find(el => el.Event.StartTime >= '2019-12-11T15:00:00')) // map into that element
);


<ion-content>
  <ng-container *ngIf="firstMatch$ | async as item">
    <ion-item>{{item.Event.StartTime | date:'shortTime'}}</ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

code is a lot more powerful than template, use it.

template is hard to read and understand. it's unclear to me if you were even trying to show only ONE `ion-item` (for the first matching element across all items) or multiple (for the first matching element in EACH item). shown both answers.

Comment: Thank you very much, @bryan60 !!